# How should one attach an XDocument to a MailMessage in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I have a C# form whose input I am aiming to turn into an xml document to attach to an email sent to myself. So far I've got an XDocument which I believe is complete, and I have also figured out how to attach a .txt to the MailMessage with:

```
MailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("[...]\test.txt"));
```

My understanding is that I could use

```
XDocument.Save("[...]\formData.xml");
```

to save the file and then

```
MailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("[...]\formData.xml"));
```

to load and attach it, but this seems wasteful.

Does anyone have a better way of going about this? I figure there must be a way to attach the XDocument without having to go to the file system like that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the Attachment class; you can add attachments by numerous other methods than just from a file, such as from a stream or string content:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx

Comment: It looks like I want to get the XDocument to output into a stream object then, which helps. I'll look into that.

Comment: FYI to others looking at this solution, I completed the implementation by creating a MemoryStream object (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()), creating an XMLWriter object (XMLWriter xw = XMLWriter.Create(ms)), writing to the XMLWriter (XDocument.WriteTo(xw)), closing the XMLWriter (xw.Close()), setting the position of the MemoryStream to 3 to get rid of some extra characters showing up at the beginning (mw.Position = 3), and lastly making my attachment with the stream (new Attachment(mw,"formData.xml")). Cheers